# Why POI costs so much memory to handle xlsx

Tags: apache-poi

I have a xlsx file with size of 90MB, not very big.

Firstly I use XSSFWorkbook to read it and I get an OutOfMemory error. Well, I change to use XSSF and SAX (Event API) to read.

When I try to write xlsx file, the doc https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf tells
"SXSSF flushes sheet data in temporary files (a temp file per sheet) and the size of these temporary files can grow to a very large value. For example, for a 20 MB csv data the size of the temp xml becomes more than a gigabyte."

Why it costs so many storages?

Comment: SXSSFWorkbook can be made to work efficiently - maybe you have a mistake in your code - you should provide your code so that people can review it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Microsoft Office files of version 2007 and above are [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) files. This are ZIP archives containing XML files and other embedded files in a special directory structure.

The memory consumption results from the used XML format.

Lets have an example:

CSV:

```
Name, Class, Amount
Name1, Class1, 1234.56
```

Lenght: 43 characters.

**Minimum** Sheet-XML:

```xml
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
 <dimension ref="A1"/>
 <sheetViews>
  <sheetView workbookViewId="0" tabSelected="true"/>
 </sheetViews>
 <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15.0"/>
 <sheetData>
  <row r="1">
   <c r="A1" t="inlineStr">
    <is>
     <t>Name</t>
    </is>
   </c>
   <c r="B1" t="inlineStr">
    <is>
     <t>Class</t>
    </is>
   </c>
   <c r="c1" t="inlineStr">
    <is>
     <t>Amount</t>
    </is>
   </c>
  </row>
  <row r="2">
   <c r="A2" t="inlineStr">
    <is>
     <t>Name1</t>
    </is>
   </c>
   <c r="B2" t="inlineStr">
    <is>
     <t>Class1</t>
    </is>
   </c>
   <c r="B2" t="n">
    <v>1234.56</v>
   </c>
  </row>
 </sheetData>
 <pageMargins bottom="0.75" footer="0.3" header="0.3" left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75"/>
</worksheet>
```

Lenght: 854 characters.

So the sheer amount of used text bytes is 20 times higher. And this is only a very simple example.

Each cell value has a minimum overhead of 56 characters:

```xml
 <c r=".." t="inlineStr">
  <is>
   <t></t>
  </is>
 </c>
```

compared to the CSV data.

The resulting `*.xlsx` file is a ZIP file, which is using compression. But the temporary sheet-files are not compressed by default to save time and random access memory. But [the resource you linked](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) fully states:

> SXSSF flushes sheet data in temporary files (a temp file per sheet)
> and the size of these temporary files can grow to a very large value.
> For example, for a 20 MB csv data the size of the temp xml becomes
> more than a gigabyte. **If the size of the temp files is an issue, you
> can tell SXSSF to use gzip compression:**
>
> ```
> SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
> wb.setCompressTempFiles(true); // temp files will be gzipped
> ```

So it provides a solution when the size of the temp files is an issue. Of course this costs time and random access memory.

But, as told already, using XML as file format comes with its own costs.

When it comes to the question why Excel uses XML then for `*.xlsx`, the answer is complex and might be opinion based.

There are advantages over the plain text CSV. For example, different data types can be stored more save. Storing of data formatting is possible. Also storing of cell styling and formatting is possible... Apart from all what CSV never will be able to store: drawings, pictures, charts, cell-comments, ...

But this also was/is true for the former binary BIFF format used by `*.xls`. And this had much less memory usage because binary formats are much closer to binary computing.

But all the binary Office formats was closed source and Microsoft was under pressure to publish the file format definitions. And XML was the most common used format for Office files at that time. There was OpenOffice already for example. So...

OpenOffice uses the [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) file format. This also are ZIP archives containing XML files and other embedded files in a special directory structure. But the internally structure and the used XML schemas are different from Microsoft's `Office Open XML`.

The above is about the memory overhead of XML. But why Apache POI needs even more memory than that while working with Office Open XML formats?

Microsoft Office parses the XML into objects in a closed source proprietary binary format in random access memory while opening the files. OpenOffice/Libreoffice do it similiary but using open source code. Then it operates using that binary format only. The XML is only parsed while opening and only generated when saving the files. That's more efficent in terms of memory usage than operating on the XML objects directly.

Apache POI uses Java objects of classes which got created from XML schema using [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/). That means internally in background while parsing the XML each XML element get it's own Java class and it's own Java object in Memory. That produces additionally memory overhead to the pure XML-text overhead. All changes are made using those objects. Thus all those objects need to stay in memory until the XML gets saved into file.

Comment: Is that not the cost of XML format?  Easy to just code something new and drop it into place and the system just accepts the new element as part of the core code, the downside is that you have to store much more data on things that might not "need" to be tracked but are essential to keep formatting uniform.

Comment: @easleyfixed: Is that not exactly what I have told in my answer?

Comment: Ops I meant to respond to the question not your answer,my bad, but yeah that is a good explanation of how this happens.  I also like that 90 MB for an XML is considered a small file :)

Comment: Does Window Excel also need to take so much memory to handle xlsx file?

Comment: @Master Qiao: No. Microsoft Office parses the XML into objects in a closed source proprietary binary format in random access memory while opening the files. Then it operates using that binary format only. The XML is only generated when saving. That's more efficent in terms of memory usage than operating on the XML objects directly.