# Apache POI Memory Usage

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there a way to optimize Apache POI usage without using streaming? If I have a 63mb excel file with 500k rows, converting the file to CSV uses up over 7gb of RAM.

As a source file, I downloaded [customers-500000.csv](https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files/raw/main/files/customers/customers-500000.zip) from GitHub [datablist/sample-csv-files](https://github.com/datablist/sample-csv-files), opened it in Excel, and saved it as an .xlsx with no other changes.

The code itself is fairly straight forward:

```java
try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file, null, false)) {
 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
 formatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
 try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath); CSVPrinter csvWriter =  CSVFormat.Builder.create(CSVFormat.RFC4180).setAutoFlush(true).build()) {
 Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Row row = iterator.next();
   for (int colNum = 0; colNum <= row.getLastCellNum(); colNum++) {
     Cell cell = row.getCell(colNum);
     values.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
   }
   csvWriter.printRecord(values);
   csvWriter.flush();
 }
}
```

Based on profiling, we are using 114x more memory than the file size itself, is there a way to get this to a more reasonable state?

[image: profiling]

[image: heapdump]

Comment: Why you don't want to use streaming? This seems a perfect use case for streaming if it is supported.

Comment: @aled streaming has some limitations and usually comes with some caveats. IMO a 60mb file shouldn't need special handling given how small that is by today's standards

Comment: The size of the file and the memory needed to process it are two different things as you are noticing. Also the input file may be compressed.

Comment: The input file is not compressed, it's a pure ~60mb file. There's no reason it should take over 7gb of memory

Comment: "The input file is not compressed": Of course it is. A `*.xlsx` file is in Office Open XML format. That is a ZIP archive containing XML files an other files in a special directory structure. "There's no reason it should take...": The ZIP needs to be unpacked. The XML needs to be interpreted. Relations need to be followed and after that probably other XML needs to be interpreted for each relation ...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72701730/why-poi-costs-so-much-memory-to-handle-xlsx/72703722#72703722

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader-sample is one of a number of streaming examples that you could use as a starting point. I would recommend using a lib like commons-csv to do proper CSV output though. There are other streaming examples at https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html

Comment: @PJFanning I'm actually using your library now (have been using it for a few years)! Thanks for creating and maintaining it - quick question, are there any restrictions / caveats when using streaming mode? If I understand correctly we won't be able to recalculate formula values (which is fine), but are there any other limitations for just reading a file?

Comment: @AxelRichter I saw that, but it doesn't explain the original question. The raw text is 63mb, the XLSX is 80mb. If I unzip the XLSX, the contents are 324MB. 7gb RAM is much more than I would anticipate it taking to process.

Comment: Tried to explain it more in my answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72701730/why-poi-costs-so-much-memory-to-handle-xlsx/72703722#72703722